# How to work with multiple screens and x2go?

Tags: linux, screen, remote-desktop

I am using a linux machine, and i have two screens.
I am also using a remote desktop application to work on some remote linux machine.

I connect to the remote machine, and hit the Ctrl+Alt+F in order to make the remote screen take control.

My problem is that the Ctrl+Alt+F - when using two screens, only make the'm to one large screens, and what is to have two screens that i will be able to open windows independently.

How can i make the'm independent screens?